# Semantic way of adding an advertisement inside the <main> element?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am planning to insert an advertisement in the middle of the page content while not breaking accessibility and semantics. My page has its contents inside a `<main>` element, but I am confused if I should use an `<aside>` or `<div role="complementary">` to nest the advertisement.

What confuses me more is that [W3C's documentation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_landmarks_to_identify_regions_of_a_page#Description) says:

> complementary: Any section of the document that supports the main content, yet is separate and meaningful on its own.

and in [Example 1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_landmarks_to_identify_regions_of_a_page#Example_1) below the page, it shows:

> ```
> <div id="rightsideadvert" role="complementary">....an advertisement here...</div>
> ```

My understanding is that not all advertisements (like Google Ads) would support or relate to the main content. What is the appropriate markup to use?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Test page</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
</head>
<body>

<main>
<!-- main content -->

<aside>
<!-- advertisement -->
</aside>

<!-- main content continues -->
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`aside` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#the-aside-element) should be used. Its definition explicitly mentions advertisements:

> The element can be used […] **for advertising** […] and for other content that is considered separate from the main content of the nearest ancestor sectioning content.

The `aside` element has the `complementary` role by default (so it should not be added explicitly).

Unless the ad is integrated with the content, it would be better to have it outside of the `main` element. But if that’s not possible, like in your case, using `aside` in `main` seems to be the best option available.

WAI-ARIA says for the [`complementary`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-wai-aria-1.1-20171214/#complementary) role:

> If the complementary content is completely separable from the main content, it may be appropriate to use a more general role.

But the other roles allowed for the `aside` element (`feed`, `note`, `search` or `presentation`) don’t seem to be suitable.